# Does LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized<T> have an explicit promise of thread safety?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-4.0, lazy-initialization

I'd like to make a Lazy property that can be tested with property injection.  If I were to use a Lazy field, I don't see how I would be able to inject my own during testing.  Here's my code:

```
private IExpensive expensive;
private bool expensiveInitialized;
private object expensiveLockingObject = new object();

public IExpensive Expensive
{
   get
   {
      LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref expensive, ref expensiveInitialized, ref expensiveLockingObject,
         () => new Expensive(myStaticArg1, myStaticArg2, ...));

      return expensive;
   }
   internal protected set
   {
      expensiveInitialized = true;
      expensive = value;
   }
}
```

I am wondering if there's a promise from BCL team that this code is thread-safe?  It was not clear from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazyinitializer.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation link:

> The methods of LazyInitializer are thread-safe and may be called from multiple threads concurrently.